# List comprehension Python - continue

Tags: python, list-comprehension

i have this piece of simple code:

```
d[]-----> List of matched objects
p = []
for w in d:
    if w is None:
        continue
    else:
        q = (w.group())
        p.append(q)
```

i have a list of macth objects that has None objects and the rest are strings

i´m trying to append the strings into a list but i´m finding it difficult with list comprehensions, specially the "continue", i tried the all() statement but with no luck:

```
p = [w.group() for w in d if w not None ] --- this obviously does not work
```

Any help will be really appreciated

Comment: What about this doesn't work? It looks like (other than missing the `is` in `if w is not None ]`) it should work.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You just had to use `is` operator to compare your object against `None`, like this

```
p = [w.group() for w in d if w is not None]
```

But you can simply rely on the truthiness of the data in this case, like this

```
p = [w.group() for w in d if w]
```